# How to make a batch file to find files in the current directory and operate

Tags: batch

So I'm trying to make a batch to operate in different pc's so the directory is dynamic but the folder names in the directory will be the same. It moves some jpg images out of the 'Output' folder, removes the png ones from the 'Chapter X' folder and deletes the output folder.

My 2 problems are;

I don't know how to make it repeat for, let's say 100 chapters. (The names go like Chapter 2, Chapter 3 etc)

The last line deletes the Output's contents, I want it to delete the folder itself.

What I did so far:

```
set mypath="%~dp0"
move %mypath%\"Chapter 1"\Output\*.* %mypath%\"Chapter 1"
del %mypath%\"Chapter 1"\*.png*
del /Q %mypath%\"Chapter 1"\Output
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are putting quotes on the wrong places, also if you only want to move png or jpg use *.png *.jpg. To delete a folder you use rd (remove directory) to delete files you use del.

```
@echo off
set "mypath=%~dp0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad *chapter*') do (
move "%%a\Output\*.*" "%%a"
del /q "%%a\*.png"
RD /q /s "%%a\Output"
)
exit
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!